# Как сделать последовательный ввод значений пользователем в боте?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть бот ВК, пользователь должен написать 3 значения в отдельных сообщениях подряд, чтобы потом произвести с ними определенное действие. Как лучше всего решить данную задачу? Пробовал создавать объект для пользователя и в него закидывать значения, но после, например, сбоя программы по какому-либо поводу у меня демон поднимет бота, но объекта уже не будет. Есть идея при каждом вводе значения делать сохранение обновленного объекта в файл, но мне кажется есть лучше варианты.

Comment: Лучше варианта нет. Только запись куда-либо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легче всего, по моему мнению, заносить ID пользователя и текущее значение в Redis.

В таком случае вылет бота никак не помешает продолжить диалог

Comment: Почему именно Redis? Не подойдет другая СУБД?

Comment: Да в целом можете что угодно использовать, хоть в текстовый файл сохранять. Но я думаю, что Redis для таких задачей подходит больше всего